# Plotting a line and surface together with correct occlusion

Tags: python, matplotlib, surface

I'm looking to plot a 2D probability distribution with one of its marginals in a single plot using Python and matplotlib. I'm almost there, but the line in the plot is always drawn in front of the surface, instead of being occluded properly. How do I fix this?

```
import numpy as np

import scipy.stats as stats

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

delta = 0.05
f = 0.5

X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta),
                   np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta))
xy = np.hstack((X.flatten()[:, None], Y.flatten()[:, None]))

p1 = stats.multivariate_normal.pdf(xy, mean=[1, -1], cov=(np.eye(2) * 0.28 * f))
p2 = stats.multivariate_normal.pdf(xy, mean=[-1, 1], cov=(np.eye(2) * 0.5 * f))

p = 0.3 * p1 + 0.7 * p2
Z = p.reshape(len(X), len(X))

plt.plot(X[0, :], np.zeros(len(X)) + 3, np.sum(Z, 0) * 0.05) # , color='red')

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, alpha=1.0, cmap='jet', linewidth=0.1, rstride=2, cstride=2)

ax.set_xlabel('Object colour')
ax.set_ylabel('Illumination colour')
ax.set_zlabel('Probability density')
ax.set_zlim(min(cont_offset, np.min(Z)), max(np.max(Z), cont_offset))

plt.show()
```

Comment: plt.plot has a zorder argument, but I'm not sure that's meaningful in a 3D axes.

Comment: mltools is a small library I made, I rewrote the code to use scipy instead so it can be run without edits. zorder does not seem to work in my case.

Comment: also missing cont_offset in the sample code, but zorder isn't working for me either. 3D should be handling it. People usually recommend mayavi for 3d plotting; can you try that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in `contour` function at least gets the z-order right; if you don't want the full thing, you could cheat with a calculated `Z`. To start, replacing your call to `plt.plot` with this:

```
from matplotlib import cm
cset = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, zdir='y', offset=3, cmap='binary')
cset = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, zdir='x', offset=-3, cmap='Blues')
```

[image]

Faking up Z's for the contours, one way:

```
from matplotlib import cm
Zys = np.zeros_like(Z)
Zys[60,:] = Z.max(0)
cset = ax.contour(X, Y, Zys, zdir='y', offset=3, cmap='binary')
Zys = np.zeros_like(Z)
Zys[:,60] = Z.max(1)
cset = ax.contour(X, Y, Zys, zdir='x', offset=-3, cmap='Blues')
```

[image]
More ambitiously, somewhere in the `contour` code they're calculating the z-order...

Comment: Great, thanks very much. This works, although I do have to cheat by passing in a Z which is constant over one axis.

    contour_plot = ax.contour(X, Y, np.tile(marginal, [len(marginal), 1]), zdir='y', offset=3)

Comment: Ha, glad it worked! I was just working on a *different* way of force-feeding `contour`. Pity it's calculating more contours than it needs to.